# How to subscribe to future incoming ERC-20 token events?

Tags: web3j

I'm using web3j to subscribe to my ERC-20 token transfer events with [transferEventObservable](https://github.com/blk-io/erc20-rest-service/blob/master/src/main/java/io/blk/erc20/generated/HumanStandardToken.java#L67): 
`humanStandardToken.transferEventObservable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).subscribe()`.
However, it only replays existing transfer events. How to subscribe to future incoming events?

Comment: On which network and node are you working (main/ropsten/rinkeby, geth/parity/ganache)?

Comment: Private testnet and geth.

Comment: do you use the same code as on https://github.com/blk-io/erc20-rest-service/tree/master/src/main/resources/solidity/contract or do you have your own smart contract?